# How to write schedule action using technial menu odoo

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, odoo

I want to write schedule action using front end.I mean I go to setting--> techinal-->schedule action and create and I want to add the following code.How can I do that?

```
@api.model
    def fix_currency(self):
        fix = self.env.cr.execute("update res_currency set rounding='0.01000' WHERE name='USD'")
        fix = self.env.cr.execute("update res_currency set decimal_places='2' WHERE name='USD'")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access to `env` inside Code Python page, and you can execute your queries:

```
env.cr.execute("update res_currency set rounding='0.01000' WHERE name='USD'")
env.cr.execute("update res_currency set decimal_places='2' WHERE name='USD'")
```

I hope this answer can be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can put this code into the Python Code tab of the schedule action.

Make sure that it is the same model.

```
model.fix_currency()
```

Comment: I can write in my module and can use ir.cron.But I want to make without using any custom moudle.I just want to add in front end

Comment: Actually my case is  I want to use query in schedule action and want to write code in odoo front end.For special case, I can't use my custom addons.